# VSTS: What is the cheapest option to run the browser based testing in the VSTS?

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops

We already have 2 Test Manager extension licenses which are assigned to Basic users who develop tests. We need to have an ability to run solely browser based testing in the VSTS by, let's say 10 users.

- What is the cheapest option to accomplish that?
- Can those users be Stakeholders or they have to have at least Basic access license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and only the Basic/VS access level is required for the users to be able to test the tests which were authored by somebody else. There is no need Test Extension in order to be able to test.

Comment: You can do additional things with Test Extension. On the other hand, you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Basic access level is required, so you need to buy basic access license for each user, also Test Manager extension license is required too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Starian! Would you be so kind to specify: do the users who are going to run tests require Test Manager extensions along with the Basic licences or just the Basic licenses?

Comment: Both Test Manager extensions and Basic licence are required. The Visual Studio subscribers are ok too. https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/